# After Effects Expression (if layer is a CompItem)

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to make slight modification at line 5 of below After Effects expression. Line 5 checks if the layer is visible and active but I have tried to add an extra check that the layer should not be a comp item. (In my project, layers are either text or image layer and I beileve an image layer means a comp item). Somehow the 'instanceof' method to ensure that layer should not be a comp item is not working. Please advise how to fix this error, thanks.

```
   txt = "";
   for (i = 1; i <= thisComp.numLayers; i++){
      if (i == index) continue;
         L = thisComp.layer(i);
           if ((L.hasVideo && L.active) && !(thisComp.layer(i) instanceof CompItem)){
          txt = i + " / " + thisComp.numLayers + " / " + L.text.sourceText.split(" ").length;
       break;
       }
    }
    txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `compItem` is available only in ExtendScript, you can actually check the properties available in the {my_layer}.`source` object.

Here's a working example (AE CC2018, CC2019 & CC2020): [layer_is_comp.aep](https://url.io/layer_is_precomp)

The expression would be something similar to:

```
function isComp (layer)
{
  try
  {
    /*
    - used for when the layer doesn't have a ['source'] key or layer.source doesn't have a ['numLayers'] key
    - ['numLayers'] is an object key available only for comp objects so it's ok to check against it
    - if ['numLayers'] is not found the expression will throw an error hence the try-catch
    */
    if (layer.source.numLayers) return true;
    else return false;
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    return false;
  }
}

try
{
  // prevent an error when no layer is selected
  isComp(effect("Layer Control")(1)) ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
catch (e)
{
  'please select a layer';
}
```

For your second question, you can check if a layer is a TextLayer by verifying that it has the `text.sourceText` property.

Example:

```
function isTextLayer (layer)
{
  try
  {
    /*
    - prevent an expression error if the ['text'] object property is not found
    */
    var dummyVar = layer.text.sourceText;

    return true;
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I will give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up expressions and Extendscript. The `compItem` class is an Extendscript class and I'm pretty sure that it isn't available for expressions.

I'd suggest reading the docs: https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/user-guide.html?topic=/after-effects/morehelp/automation.ug.js

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any idea what should be the syntax to denote an image in AE expressions? In other words, is there any thing that would differentiate an image layer from a text layer using AE expressions?